# Understanding the philosophy behind flexbox

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I've done everything to understand why this issue occurs but with no gain. I have a very simple screen in a react-native application that renders a container `View` with 2 children: the first one with a fixed width and height while the second has `flex: 1`. As I understand, I expect for the first item to have its fixed size and the second one to take the entire rest space of the screen. However, this situation is conditional. when I leave `alignItems` of the container View to its default `stretch`, I get the expected result. When I set it to `center` so that I center the first item with its fixed width in the center, the second item totally disappears which made me mad.

Here is my simple screen:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import { SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR, POST_BACKGROUND_COLOR, DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR } from '../../utils/colors';
import i18n from '../../utils/i18n';
import FontIcon from '../../components/Deaf/Default/FontIcon/FontIcon';
import DefaultTextInput from '../../components/Deaf/Default/DefaultTextInput/DefaultTextInput';
import DefaultText from '../../components/Deaf/Default/DefaultText/DefaultText';

export default class YoutubeInput extends PureComponent {
    renderInput = () => {
      return(
        <DefaultTextInput 
          style = { styles.input }
          placeholder = { i18n.t( 'input_screen.what_watching' ) }
          onChangeText = { this.onChangeInput }
          value = { this.state.input }
          multiline = { true }
        />
      );
    };

    renderAddIcon = () => {
      return(
        <FontIcon 
          name = 'add'
          font = 'Ion'
          onPress = { this.onAddLink }
        />
      );
    };

    renderInputContainer = () => {
        return(
            <View style = { styles.linkInputContainer }>
                { this.renderInput() }
                { this.renderAddIcon() }
            </View>
        );
    };

    renderLinksList = () => {
        const { links } = this.state;

        return(
            <View style = { {flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'} }>
              { links.map( this.renderLink ) }            
        </View>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <View style = { styles.container }>
                { this.renderInputContainer() }
                { this.renderLinksList() }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = EStyleSheet.create( {
    '$width': '95%',
    '$marginVertical': '5rem',
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR
    },
    input: {
        flex: 1
    },
    linkInputContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '$width',
        height: '50rem',
        marginVertical: '$marginVertical',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: POST_BACKGROUND_COLOR
    },
    linkContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '$width',
        height: 50,
        marginVertical: '$marginVertical',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR,
        backgroundColor: POST_BACKGROUND_COLOR
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding **alignItems: "center"** to view and has default **flexDirection:"column"** . Childs  will be in center but the width will be according to content of child . First child have width attribute so it is showing but second does not have so it will have content width by default if you apply **alignItems: "center"**

**Try to add width="100%" to renderLinksList component**

To align second item you do not have to add alignItems to parent you can add in child to make it in center

```
linkInputContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '$width',
        height: '50rem',
        marginVertical: '$marginVertical',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: POST_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
```

Comment: This solution will center the children of linkInputContainer but not the component itself.